# Current of opposite charges

Tags: electric-current

Positive charges move in a direction opposite to that of a negative charge, right?

So how could we know the current (flow of charges) say in a wire if opposite charges move in different directions? If we choose the reference direction to be to the right, we'd be neglecting the current of charges moving to the left.

I have a misunderstanding about the concept of current, and I hope someone would make it clear to me. Thank you.

Comment: I am pretty sure that this is a duplicate, but you may want to read https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hall_effect. We can distinguish the polarity of charge carriers in conductors using the Hall effect.

Comment: The reference given by @CuriousOne (Hall effect in semiconductors) shows that if both negative and positive carriers are present the sign of the Hall coefficient is given by the sign of the carrier which has the largest contribution to the charge carrying process.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because when we talk about the current direction we *always mean* the direction of positive charge. It's a convention. If positive charge is present or not.

If in reality it actually is negative charge moving (like electrons in wires), then remember that a negative charge moving one way corresponds directly to a positive charge moving the other way.

In that way the convention takes both types of charges into account. Think of a solution for example with ions of both positive and negative charge. Here both are present. But the convention takes *both* into account.

If 10 positive charges move left and 10 negative move right, then that corresponds to 20 positive moving left. Everything is taking into account.

Answer (score 0):

Just get the fact that the electrons repel a negative charge and therefore the flow of the current will be in a direction which is opposite to that of the battery's negative end, be it in any direction.